# From selected checkboxes to an email to me

Tags: php, jquery, html, email

I'm new with PHP. I need some help with this problem:
I'm making sort of webshop, where you can select projects and if you selected the projects you can send an email at the bottom of the page,The email function works and the jquery selecting function also but i want to combine them so i can get an email with the projects the costumer selected.

PHP

```
<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?> 
<form ....
</form

<?php
    } 
else              
    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
    $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($phone=="")||($message==""))
        {
    echo "vul alstublieft alles in, probeer het opnieuw <a href=\"\">in te vullen.</a>";
      }
    else{   
      $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
    mail("gradeontwerp@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
    echo "De email is verstuurd!";
      }
    }  
?>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
'use strict';
  /* global console:true */
  $('#verzenden').click(function(){
    $.each($('.btn input'), function (index, value) { 
        console.log(index + '' + $(value).parent().text(),$(value).is(':checked')); 

      if($(value).is(':checked')){
        console.log('checked');
      }
      else {
          console.log('unchecked');
      }

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. It's unclear what you're asking in this question, or if you got any error messages.